# Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions, even with getChildFragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity with a viewpager that contains 3 fragments.
In one of the 3 fragments I have another viewpager, now I learned that when you want te embed a fragment in a fragment you gotta use getChildFragmentManager but for some reason it doesn't work with me.

I have an activity:
HomeActivity

And 3 fragments, one of them:
ProfileFragment

In here I use this for my viewpager:

```
// Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerProfileAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

This is the ViewPagerProfileAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerProfileAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerProfileAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            EventsFragment tab1 = new EventsFragment();
            return tab1;
        }
        else           // As we are having 3 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            AttendsFragment tab2 = new AttendsFragment();
            return tab2;
        }


    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

I still get this error:

```
03-13 14:09:02.150    5040-5040/com.laurenswuyts.witpa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.laurenswuyts.witpa, PID: 5040
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1461)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:420)
            at com.laurenswuyts.witpa.Fragments.Profile.ProfileFragment.onActivityCreated(ProfileFragment.java:206)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1794)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:967)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1896)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2059)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
            at android.view.ViewRoot
```

Line 206 is pager.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself.
For everyone who does use getChildFragmentManager but still has error's.
Give the pager and the tabs a different name otherwise it will not work and intervene with your other pager and tabs.

Comment: Also maybe the error is not from "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions" itself. Analyze the logcat and look for other errors before the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions".

Comment: What you mean with `Give the pager and the tabs a different name`. Can you please explain? I have the same issue @Laurenswuyts

Comment: @ErenUtku if the id of tab1 is = "tab" and the id of tab2 is also "tab" than it will collide with eachother and give problems

Comment: Id's are not sets/gives by the user. You mean tag?